# Object pool with multiprocessing returns the same object in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have object pool to manage some resource. 
I expected to use reused resources to be created with different Processes.
But I see that all resources have the same ID and are created as new object.

---

**My result is:**

- Creating new resource =  1
- Creating new resource =  2
- Creating new resource =  3
- Creating new resource =  1
- Creating new resource =  2
- Creating new resource =  3
- Creating new resource =  1
- Creating new resource =  2
- Creating new resource =  3

---

**I expected to see something like this:**

- Creating new resource =  1
- Creating new resource =  2
- Creating new resource =  3
- Using existing resource =  1
- Using existing resource =  2
- Using existing resource =  3
- Using existing resource =  1
- Using existing resource =  2
- Using existing resource =  3

OR:

- Creating new resource =  1
- Creating new resource =  2
- Creating new resource =  3
- Creating new resource =  4
- Creating new resource =  5
- Creating new resource =  6
- Creating new resource =  7
- Creating new resource =  8
- Creating new resource =  9

  ---

import multiprocessing

`class Resource(object):
    def __init__(self, ID):
        self.id = ID


class ObjectPool:
    __id = 0
    __instance = None
    __resources = list()

    def __init__(self):
        if ObjectPool.__instance != None:
            raise NotImplemented("This is a singleton class.")

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():
        if ObjectPool.__instance == None:
            ObjectPool.__instance = ObjectPool()
        return ObjectPool.__instance

    def getResource(self):
        if len(self.__resources) > 0:
            resourse = self.__resources.pop(0)
            print "Using existing resource = ", resourse.id
            return resourse

        else:
            ObjectPool.__id += 1
            print "Creating new resource = ", ObjectPool.__id
            return Resource(ID=ObjectPool.__id)

    def returnResource(self, resource):
        self.__resources.append(resource)


POOL = ObjectPool.getInstance()


def func():
    resource = POOL.getResource()
    resource2 = POOL.getResource()
    resource3 = POOL.getResource()
    POOL.returnResource(resource)
    POOL.returnResource(resource2)
    POOL.returnResource(resource3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for n in range(3):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=func)
        process.start()`

Answer (score 1):

You never changed the value of `ObjectPool.id`, so it is always zero.

Comment: I have change it during new resource creation ObjectPool.id+1

Comment: @Helga: That doesn't change it.  That just returns one more than it.  If you do `x = 1` and then `y = x+1`, that doesn't change `x`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I see!!! I have fixed this. It was really my bug, but the general problem is still open. I have updated it. It is problem that I have new resource with the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not performing as expected because each new process created with `multiprocessing.Process` is creating a new local `POOL` instance.

That should become obvious if you add the process id to the printed messages, like:

```
import os

[...]

print "[%04d] Using existing resource = %s" % (os.getpid(), resourse.id)
```

Without more context on what a resource is, it's difficult to suggest a solution to your problem. One option would be to create a shared [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) in the *main* process and let your processes to get the shared resources from them, and maybe, add them there once they are free'd.

Or possibly use a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Semaphore) if the number of shared resources if fixed.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) for more options.